# Convert <imlib2.color r= g= b= a= > (x) > userdata to red green etc values

Tags: lua

like

```
local color_red = im:get_pixel_red(x, y)
```

searched something in imlib2 Lua but did'n find anything.

Comment: If `im` is an `imlib2.color` userdata have you tried just `im.red`, etc.? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: hi,  http://pastebin.com/p8tDfHpV  i want to have c1r c1g c1b and c1a as seperate values. The problem is that inside this for construction it does only print the full imlib2.color userdata. and that isn`t good if you want to change them.

Comment: If `c1` is the `imlib2.color` in that case then did you try just indexing it directly?

Comment: hi, i don`t want indexing but comparing and editing red green blue  per pixel in a for construct.

Comment: You asked about how to get the r/g/b value of a pixel. I'm suggesting a way to do that. I have no idea if you can assign to a pixel directly but you might be able to. Have you tried? `c1.red = 22`?

Comment: c1r =(c1.red)  works !!  Solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (given a quick look at the lua imlib2 [source code](https://github.com/asb/lua-imlib2/blob/master/limlib2.c#L87)) that you can just index the red, green and blue values right out of the `imlib2.color` userdata.

So if `c1` is a color/pixel then `c1.red` is the red value, etc.

It [looks like](https://github.com/asb/lua-imlib2/blob/master/limlib2.c#L108) you can assign values this way also `c1.red = 22`.

And, in fact, this all happens to be in the [documentation](http://asbradbury.org/projects/lua-imlib2/doc/) also.

> imlib2.color.new(red, green, blue[, alpha])
>
> Creates a new color. An error will be raised unless red, green, blue and alpha are in the range 0 <= x <= 255.
>   col.red, col.green, col.blue, col.alpha
>
> Each instance of imlib2.color has integer fields red, green, blue, and alpha which can be read and modified. An exception is raised if you try to set the value outside the range 0 <= x <= 255.